# PropertyGrid in Adobe Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, propertygrid

I'm looking for a PropertyGrid-like control for Adobe Flex, or perhaps the easiest way to create one. The main two things it should do in addition to a normal property grid are displaying categories and having different kind of editor controls to edit the data in one column.

So basically I'm looking for a control to edit key/value pairs, divided into categories, with different kinds of editor controls for different keys/rows.

I found exactly what I want right here: http://www.cnblogs.com/janyou/archive/2009/07/28/1532919.html

Though that page is in Chinese, there is no record of source code or where that component came from, etc. I can also not find any other solutions on the web (although maybe my search terms are incorrect, because I'm not entire sure how to search for it).

Answer (score 0):

i've done it using a datagrid with two columns, and this approach works just fine for me:

```
                <mx:columns>
                    <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="parameter" width="110" resizable="false">
                        <mx:itemRenderer>
                            <mx:Component>
                                <mx:Label truncateToFit="true" fontWeight="bold" />
                            </mx:Component>
                        </mx:itemRenderer>
                    </mx:DataGridColumn>
                    <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="value">
                        <mx:itemRenderer>
                            <mx:Component>
                                <mx:HBox width="100%" height="100%" horizontalScrollPolicy="off" verticalScrollPolicy="off"
                                    currentState="{(data.parameterType) == 'bool' ? 'checkboxState' : 'baseState'}">
                                    <mx:states>
                                        <mx:State name="baseState">
                                            <mx:AddChild>
                                                <mx:Label truncateToFit="true" text="{data.value}" paddingLeft="2" />
                                            </mx:AddChild>
                                        </mx:State>
                                        <mx:State name="chbState">
                                            <mx:AddChild>
                                                <mx:CheckBox selected="{data.value &amp;&amp; parseInt(data.value)}" paddingLeft="5" />
                                            </mx:AddChild>
                                        </mx:State>
                                    </mx:states>
                                </mx:HBox>
                            </mx:Component>
                        </mx:itemRenderer>
                    </mx:DataGridColumn>
                </mx:columns>
```

Answer (score -1):

Surely this is just a List control with your item renderer instantiating the correct control based on whatever the data is... i.e. if the data is an array, show in a combobox, if it's a number show in a stepper, if its text show in TextInput.

This should be very easy to achieve.

Comment: A List or a DataGrid? Also, how could one make the categories? I don't blieve that's standard behaviour of List controls.

Comment: A List. I think its fairly doable if you take a look at some of the stuff that Alex Harui's done in the past. It really is just a different itemrenderer.